# JavaScript: detect if Symbol.toStringTag is supported

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Does this function definitely detect support of `@@toStringTag` sefely in any environment?

```
function hasToStringTagSymbol() {
    if (Symbol && (typeof Symbol() == "symbol") && !!Symbol.toStringTag) {
        var xTest = function () { };
        xTest.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Test";
        xTest = new xTest();
        return toString.call(xTest) == "[object Test]";
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could write a test for each scenario you expect to catch?

Comment: There are browsers that dont sypport ecmascript, so i have to detect if it is possible to use this symbol.

Comment: `delete Symbol` before your test, would that not simulate it not being present?

Comment: Feature detection example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046635/javascript-es6-cross-browser-detection

Comment: The question possibly results from wrong premises. If browsers don't support ES6, the one should start with polyfill installation. Symbol and toString can be easily polyfilled. If you're after specific ES6 functions in your app, it may be better to focus on those that cannot be polyfilled, at least in old browsers.

Comment: @estus Before main script is loaded i detect if feature is present, if not then polyfill runs .

Comment: @AndreyGodyaev This is how core-js works. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you can just use it, unless you're unhappy with its detection algos (it will force a polyfill if the feature is present but not compliant to the specs)

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code doesn't detect properly polyfilled `Symbol.toStringTag`. While it is possible to polyfill `Symbol` and its effect on `toString` (this is done by `core-js` in particular), it's impossible to introduce new primitive type for `typeof`. The code above doesn't test that `Symbol` is a function as well (and it doesn't really need to create a new symbol).

It should be more like:

```
if (typeof Symbol !== "undefined" && Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag) {
    var o = {};
    o[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Test";
    return toString.call(o) == "[object Test]";
}
```

`Symbol` and its effect on `toString` can be easily polyfilled. If a developer is after specific JS features in the app, it may be better to focus on those that cannot be polyfilled, at least in old browsers. It can be `Object.setPrototypeOf` for ES5, `Proxy` for ES6 or the detection of [syntactic features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46127053/3731501).